# How do I make label (node) to appear in front of markers in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

**How do I make label (node) to appear in front of markers in pgfplots?**

For example in:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 1)
}  node[pos=0.5]{\color{green}{LABEL}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that "LABEL" appears behind the plot marker:

[image: dotlabel]

It might be a good default (or inherited from TikZ) but how do I change this behavior? (Preferably something that still allows using the `...} node[]{...};`-syntax.)

Comment: you can check the `set layers` option to send things in different layers. Markers are on top by default so should your node too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally markers are drawn on top of all plots in an `axis` environment (`clip mode=global`, default) or at least on top of the single plot (`clip mode=individual`) to avoid clipping the markers. In your code the node is part of the `plot` path and therefore behind the markers.

### Version 1

You can shift the markers in the layer `axis tick labels` which is behind  of the `main` layer:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  set layers,% using layers
  mark layer=axis tick labels% defines the layer of the marks
}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
   (0.5,0.5) (1, 1) (1.5,1.5)
  } node[pos=0.5]{\color{green}{LABEL}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that then all markers will be behind all plots in the same axis environment.

### Version 2

Set a `coordinate` in the plot path and draw the node in a `pgfonlayer` environment on the `axis foreground` layer:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}% using layers
\begin{axis}[set layers]
\addplot coordinates {
     (0.5,0.5) (1, 1) (1.5,1.5)
  } coordinate[pos=0.5](p1);% coordinate in the middle of the plot path
\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis foreground}
  \node at (p1){\color{green}{LABEL}};% draw the node in the axis foreground
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to change the layer for the node directly in their options. But maybe there is such a possibility.

### Version 3

Use `clip mode=invidual`, set a `coordinate` in the plot path and draw the node when the plot is finished:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip mode=individual]
\addplot coordinates {
   (0.5,0.5) (1, 1) (1.5,1.5)
} coordinate[pos=0.5](p1);% coordinate in the middle of the plot path
\node at (p1){\color{green}{LABEL}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Edit

From the manual v. 1.10, page 349:

> The `layers/standard` layer configuration is defined by
>
> ```
> \pgfplotsset{
>   layers/standard/.define layer set=
>     {axis background,axis grid,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,main,%
>       axis descriptions,axis foreground}
>     {
>       grid style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis grid},
>       tick style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis ticks},
>       axis line style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis lines},
>       label style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis descriptions},
>       legend style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis descriptions},
>       title style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis descriptions},
>       colorbar style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis descriptions},
>       ticklabel style= {/pgfplots/on layer=axis tick labels},
>       axis background@ style={/pgfplots/on layer=axis background},
>       3d box foreground style={/pgfplots/on layer=axis foreground},
>     },
> }
> ```

You can define a new layer set and for example add a new layer behind `main`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
  layers/mylayers/.define layer set=
    {axis background,axis grid,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,%
      axis mymarks,% additional layer behind main
      main,axis descriptions,axis foreground}
    {/pgfplots/layers/standard}% re-uses the style definitions of layers/standard
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
  set layers=mylayers,% using mylayers
  mark layer=axis mymarks% defines the layer of the marks
}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
   (0.5,0.5) (1, 1) (1.5,1.5)
  } node[pos=0.5]{\color{green}{LABEL}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Version 1 is a very simple solution and it can be set in per-axis way. But I am hesitant that I am changing the layer of all the marks in the plot. Do you know a list of all the available layers, such as `axis tick labels`?

Comment: @alfC see my edit

Answer (score 4):

Something likes this. This solution uses `background, main and foreground` skill

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
%\begin{scope}{background}
\addplot coordinates {
    (1, 1)
};
%\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\node at (axis cs: 1,1) [pos=0.5]{\color{red}LABEL};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice one. You can also use the existing pgfplots layer mechanism without invoking the PGF `backgrounds` library

Comment: @percusse : Would you please elaborate on this, perhaps in second answer?