# pgfplots: Put xlabel on layer below axis line

Tags: pgfplots, axis, pgflayers

Based on [How do I make label (node) to appear in front of markers in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184111/how-do-i-make-label-node-to-appear-in-front-of-markers-in-pgfplots), I would like to put the `xlabel` on a white background on a layer above `axis grid` and below `axis lines`. I guess this should be possible.

However, my attempt

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom, xlabel style={at={(1,0)}, above},
    axis y line=left, ylabel style={at={(0,1)}, rotate=-90, right},
    grid=major,
    xlabel style={/pgfplots/on layer=axis background, fill=white},
    xlabel={$\Delta x$ (cm)}, ylabel={$F$ (N)}]
\addplot [only marks, mark=x, thick] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in the `xlabel` partially hiding the `x axis line`:

[image]

It seems like my fumbling with layers has no effect. – What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have found a bug here. Have a look at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/186/, where I reported it.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have known that this might be a bug, nor how to report it. Let's see what C.F. says and whether it will get fixed.