# pgfplotsextra: draw on top of markers and lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using a setup that is similar to this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=-2:2,mark=x] {sin(deg(x)))};
        \pgfplotsextra{
            \draw[red,->,>=latex] (axis cs:-1,0) to (axis cs:0.1,0);
           % in reality there are more commands here
        }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code seems to draw on top of lines but not on markers, here an zoomed version
[image]

But I would like to draw on top of the lines and the markers. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the layer of the marks, see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184163/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[set layers, mark layer=axis tick labels]
        \addplot[domain=-2:2,mark=x] {sin(deg(x)))};
        \pgfplotsextra{
            \draw[red,->,>=latex] (axis cs:-1,0) to (axis cs:0.1,0);
           % in reality there are more commands here
        }
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `\pgfplotsextra` should not be used for drawing paths, and in sufficiently recent versions of pgfplots you do not need `axis cs:` and you can set this globally e.g by saying `\pgfplotsset{set layers, mark layer=axis tick labels}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,set layers, mark layer=axis tick labels}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=-2:2,mark=x] {sin(deg(x)))};
        \draw[red,->,>=latex] (-1,0) to (0.1,0);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a lot of figures where I would (potentially) like to draw stuff on. Is there an issue with globally adding `set layers, mark layer=axis tick labels` to all axis environments?

Comment: @bonanza Sure, just say `\pgfplotsset{set layers, mark layer=axis tick labels}` before/outside of the `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better alternative than `\pgfplotsextra` for drawing paths then?

Comment: @bonanza Yes, the lower code in my answer.